# DRY: don't repeat yourself in Lua

Tags: function, lua, dry, world-of-warcraft

There is a way to not rewrite the same part (the cycle `for i = 1...end`) twice?

```
local function myfunc(frame,method)
    if frame:IsShown() then
        for i = 1, #frame.buttons do
            frame.buttons[i]:HookScript("OnMouseDown", method)
        end
    else
        frame:SetScript(
            "OnShow",
            function(frame)
                for i = 1, #frame.buttons do
                    frame.buttons[i]:HookScript("OnMouseDown", method)
                end
            end
        )
    end
end
```

Where

- `IsShown()`, `HookScript()` and `SetScript()` are all in-game API

EDIT

Maybe a recursive function? It seems to work:

```
local function myfunc(frame,method)
    if frame:IsShown() then
        for i = 1, #frame.buttons do
            frame.buttons[i]:HookScript("OnMouseDown", method)
        end
    else
        frame:SetScript(
            "OnShow", --when "OnShow" is fired, IsShown() become true
            function()
                myfunc(frame,method)
            end
        )
    end
end
```

Comment: Make another function with the loop, call that function from the two places you have the loop today.

Comment: @ViaTech ok, deleted my comment too.

Comment: Question edited. Tell me if if my proposal is a good idea. I forgot the `method` argument in my original code.

Comment: Imo, no. When you need a comment just to explain the code flow it's probably too complex. I would go for a second function.